# C# ChrW(140) return a different character than in Dot Net Core

Tags: c#, encryption, unicode

I have an encrypted string in database that is encrypted using VB 6. Like If password is amiejack12 it is encrypted to "ÞÓÔØÔÞÝÖŒŒ" . I need to encrypt this string in c# in Dot Net Core. I also have reference to using Microsoft.VisualBasic; It return same character for values<127 but for code 140 Strings.ChrW(140) return \u008c while in VB6 or Dot Net Framework it returns Œ How can found its equivalent in Dot Net Core using C#
Here is my code

```
int intChar;
       string strMagic= "amiejack12";
        int intKeyChar;
        int intPosInString;
        string strMagicWord = "";
        string strKeyVal = "@ABBA@ABBA@ABBA@ABBA@ABBA@ABBA@ABBA@ABBA@";

        for (intPosInString = 0; intPosInString < strMagic.Length; intPosInString++)
        {
            intChar = 255 - Strings.Asc(strMagic.Substring(intPosInString, 1));
            intKeyChar = Strings.Asc(strKeyVal.Substring(intPosInString, 1));
            strMagicWord = strMagicWord + Strings.Chr(intChar ^ intKeyChar);
            
        }
```

It works fine if string does not contain special symbols or numeric value. In Dot net core its output is "ÞÓÔØÔÞÝÖ" while in dot net framework it is :ÞÓÔØÔÞÝÖŒŒ

Acii Value of ascii('Œ') is 140 while UNICODE('Œ') is 338

Comment: It's very difficult to call this algorithm "encryption", TBH.

Comment: `Value of ascii('Œ') is 140` - this implies a certain code page - pure ASCII is only 0 through 127. You need to specify exactly how it should work. If you wish for it to be interoperable between VB6 and C#, you'll probably need to figure out which code page VB6 uses and use the same one on the C# side with the Encoding class to convert to and from extended ASCII.

Comment: vb6 uses default code page. we did not specify any specific. Same function works in C# in Dot net . But when i upgrade my project to Dot Net Core it stops working. In MSSQl also return same value ascii('Œ') is 140